# Python lists and dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Code so far:

```
def letterFreq(words):
    s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    lst = []
    for word, year_counts in words.items():
        total = 0
        for year_count in year_counts:
            total += year_count.count
        return word, total
        for i in s:
            if i in word:
                a = i* total
                b = a/
                lst.append(b
```

Dictionary(dict = words) looks like this structure but will change as new words get added to it:

> {'airport': [YearCount( year=2007, count=175702 ), YearCount( year=2008, count=173294 )], 'request': [YearCount( year=2005, count=646179 ), YearCount( year=2006, count=677820 ), YearCount( year=2007, count=697645 ), YearCount( year=2008, count=795265 )], 'wandered': [YearCount( year=2005, count=83769 ), YearCount( year=2006, count=87688 ), YearCount( year=2007, count=108634 ), YearCount( year=2008, count=171015 )]}

I'm trying to create a new list that is in order by each letter in the alphabet, which contains the frequency that each letter occurs in total. So it would be to count the total number of
a’s for example, occurring in all the words in the input data set. This number is then divided by the total number of letters in all the words.

ex.

```
[0.03104758705050717, 0.0, 0.0, 0.03500991824543893, 0.2536276129665047, 0.0, 0.
0, 0.0, 0.013542627927787708, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.017504959122719464, 0.013542
627927787708, 0.013542627927787708, 0.10930884736053291, 0.15389906233882777, 0.
10930884736053291, 0.12285147528832062, 0.10930884736053291, 0.0, 0.017504959122
719464, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

I'm pretty stumped to any help would be appreciated

Comment: [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) would be very useful here, i think. ALso, why you `return word, total' return in loop. Is the indention changed when you pasted the code here?

Comment: I'm trying to work with those two values in my next loop. And I haven't used a counter before

Answer (score 0):

Example usage of Counter to get the fractions you want:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> out = Counter("Hello world".lower())
>>> out
Counter({'l': 3, 'o': 2, ' ': 1, 'e': 1, 'd': 1, 'h': 1, 'r': 1, 'w': 1})
>>> [out[c] for c in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
>>> freqs = [out[c] for c in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']
>>> percs = [f * 1.0 / sum(freqs) for f in freqs]
>>> percs
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```